Why exactly does time translation symmetry lead to conservation of energy?
As far as I know (and I don't know much), Noether's theorem claims that time translation invariance of the laws of physics leads to the conservation of energy. The way I understand it is that if we imagine a universe where all the laws of physics always require time as one of the inputs, then energy in this universe is not conserved.
But the laws of physics do not necessarily only describe energy, do they? There's at least linear/angular momentum, and maybe other things as well. So why is it that only energy is not conserved in the above universe? What makes time translation invariance specific to energy?

Hello! Is this of any help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/423252/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/614757/226902

Please consider writing more useful question titles, see How do we write good question titles?. I edited this one for you

Possible duplicate: Noether Theorem and Energy conservation in classical mechanics


Does Noether theorem apply only to energy conservation?

No.

The way I understand it is that if we imagine a universe where all the laws of physics always require time as one of the inputs, then energy in this universe is not conserved.

When there is explicit time dependence in the system, the energy is generally not conserved. Generally, the Hamiltonian energy will change with time as:
$$
\frac{dH}{dt} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}\;,\tag{A}
$$
where the RHS is generally not zero when there is explicit time dependence.

But the laws of physics do not necessarily only describe energy, do they?

That's right, there are other "integrals of the motion," as they say.

There's at least linear/angular momentum, and maybe other things as well.

Yes, linear momentum conservation follows from invariance under spatial translation, just like energy conservation follows from invariance under time translation.

What makes time translation invariance specific to energy?

It just is the way it is. For example, consider a classical real scalar field theory. The conserved charges associated with space-time translations are the $0\mu$ components of the stress-energy tensor, which can be written in this case as:
$$
T^{\mu}_{\nu} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \partial_\mu\phi}\partial_\nu\phi - L\delta^{\mu}_\nu\;,
$$
from which it follows that
$$
H = \int d^3x T^{00}
$$
is the conserved charge associated with time-translation invariance, i.e., the energy.
And
$$
P^i = \int d^3x T^{0i}
$$
is the conserved charge associated with space-translation invariance, i.e., the momentum.

A simple way to see how time-translation invariance leads to energy conservation is to just use Eq. (A) above.
To put a little more color on that equation, recall that the Hamiltonian energy is defined for a system with a single degree of freedom as
$$
H = p \dot q - L(q,\dot q)\;,\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\;,
$$
is the momentum, and where $q$ is the generalized coordinate.
Note that I wrote $L(q,\dot q)$ in Eq. (1) to indicate that there is no explicit time dependence in the system (so we suspect the energy will be conserved).
From Eq. (1) we have:
$$
\frac{dH}{dt} = \dot p \dot q + p\ddot q - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\dot q - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\ddot q 
$$
$$
= 0\;,\tag{2}
$$
since the second term cancels with the fourth term, by definition, and the first term cancels with the third term, by the Lagrange equations of motion. Eq. (2) says that the energy is conserved. Thus, we see that time translation invariance leads to conservation of energy.

Similarly, suppose the Lagrangian was translationally invariant. Then we have
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = 0\;,
$$
which, by the Lagrange equations of motion says:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} = 0 \equiv \frac{dp}{dt}\;.
$$
Thus, we see that space translation invariance leads to conservation of linear momentum.


As far as I know (and I don't know much), Noether's theorem claims that time translation invariance of the laws of physics leads to the conservation of energy.

That is incomplete, but not incorrect. As you noticed, there are other conservation laws, and in fact they also come from symmetries. What Noether's theorem states is that for every continuous symmetry of a physical system there is a corresponding conservation law. For example, translation symmetry leads to the conservation of linear momentum, and rotational symmetry leads to the conservation of angular momentum.

The way I understand it is that if we imagine a universe where all the laws of physics always require time as one of the inputs, then energy in this universe is not conserved.

It it worth pointing out that energy is not conserved in our Universe, because the Universe is in expansion (hence, it gets bigger, and time translation symmetry does not apply). At local scales this is negligible, but it is relevant at large scales.

I think the discussion of energy conservation in the Universe is misleading. Energy non-conservation in FLRW coordinates arises from time-translation asymmetry. But the coordinates are not the physics. I could make energy conservation fail in any physical system just by describing it with time-dependent coordinates. The challenge with global energy conservation in cosmology is deeper than that.

@Sten FLRW is not stationary in the general case. This is a coordinate-independent statement

I think we're using different language. I contend that any claim about FLRW is a coordinate-dependent statement, because FLRW is a metric, which is defined in terms of coordinates.

@Sten that is incorrect. Metrics are not coordinate-dependent in any way. The components are coordinate-dependent, but the metric tensor itself is a geometric object that independs of any coordinate-choices.

Anyway, if we are speaking in coordinate-independent terms, what is non-stationary is that the density decreases in time, and not anything about expansion directly. Moreover, this only has implications for test particles in the prescribed background. It is misleading to say things like "At local scales this is negligible, but it is relevant at large scales" because whether energy can be conserved is not related to scale, it's related to whether there is a background that you treat as external. Deviations from energy conservation in (e.g.) galaxies are not negligible, they are nonexistent.

@Sten What is non-stationary is the absence of a timelike Killing vector field. There are deviations from energy conservation in galaxies because there is still expansion going on, but if you integrate the energy density over a galaxy you will find it changes very little. It is existent, because the background is still expanding, but it is negligible

@Sten Can you write down the quantity you believe is conserved in a general FLRW spacetime? Note that standard definitions of a conserved "energy" in GR do not extend to FLRW, for example the ADM mass is only well-defined in asymptotically flat spacetimes, and the Komar mass in stationary spacetimes (meaning spacetimes with a timelike Killing vector).

@NíckolasAlves No, there is no expansion going on in galaxies. That is exactly the kind of misconception I am trying to address! The non-stationary nature of the FLRW solution is connected to the evolution of the background. Inside the galaxy, the background is not present. It's not just negligible -- there is no component of matter (or whatever) that follows anything like the Hubble flow. There is a background outside the galaxy, but its decrease in density over time has no influence on dynamics in the galaxy.

@Andrew There is not a useful concept of a globally conserved energy in cosmology (to my knowledge). I do not claim that there is. Rather, I am concerned about how this idea gets (mis)translated into more general claims about energy conservation.

I would just like to point out that energy "not being conserved" in our Universe depends on the details of what you mean.
If you take the expanding universe to be god given then phenomena within that background will be described by a system whose "physical laws" depend on time. Hence you can say this system (which does not include the universe itself) does not conserve energy. But really it is better to say that it has no definition of energy.
The above is often what we do in practice but it can lead to confusion for somebody new to Noether's theorem. Indeed it is strange to say "the laws of physics depend on time" when most relativists who think about cosmic expansion every day don't believe this to be the case. Someone who tries to be as fundamental as possible will write down a theory which attempts to describe the expansion of the universe itself (e.g. Einstein's equation). And in this case, the fact that our universe happens to be expanding has no bearing on the symmetries. Symmetries are properties of a system and they lead to quantities that are conserved by any solution to the equations of motion. So the properties of a particular solution can't be used to rule out what symmetries were there in the first place.
The statement that our universe does not conserve energy (while true in one sense) has been thrown around fairly quickly ever since Sean Carroll wrote a blog post about it. We should also draw attention to the more fundamental statement (as Carroll does elsewhere in his writing) that the Hamiltonian vanishes in general relativity.

I'm not sure if you know special relativity or not, but time can be described as another dimension. As you stated, time translation invariance gives us conservation of energy. However, spacial translation invariance gives us conservation of momentum. Effectively, time is to space what energy is to momentum. This is why energy is not a vector, just as time is not a vector. It may help to consider the 4-vectors of position and momentum so I will link the wikipedia page here
